# Soap server comunication on Node-red

Tags: node.js, soap, wsdl, node-red

I am triying to use node-red contrib soap library but there isnt enough example to understand.I want to use WSDL service as a local file from pc directory.I couldnt extract methods.What am I supposed to do?

Answer (score 0):

at least search for it...on their [github page](https://github.com/chameleonbr/node-red-contrib-soap) are documented steps to go